# Доступ к элементам хэша params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Заметил, что в Ruby on Rail доступ к значению хэша можно получить двумя способами: `params["product"]` и `params[:product]`. Эти способы анологичны.
Как это реализовано, ведь в Ruby `hash["k"]` и `hash[:k]` это разные вещи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметры в Ruby on Rails реализованы через класс [`Object::HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html), который наследуется от `Hash`. Его особенность заключается в том, что он автоматически приводит символические ключи к строковому значению, поэтому для доступа к параметру вы можете использовать как символ, так и строку.

Если вы посмотрите реализацию этого класса, то увидите, что у него перегружены почти все методы для работы с ключами, например

```
...
def [](key)
  super(convert_key(key))
end
...
def convert_key(key)
  key.kind_of?(Symbol) ? key.to_s : key
end
...
```

Comment: И эти методы можно определить в любом объекте, наделив его возможностью работы с таким же синтаксисом.

Comment: Ну и параметры это отдельный класс. В 4-х рельсах они были унаследованы от `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, в пятых - самостоятельный класс.

Comment: @anoam если не сложно, развейте пожалуйста вашу мысль либо в комментарии, либо в отдельном ответе (за который можно проголосовать). На сколько я вижу по документации Object::HashWithIndifferentAccess является частью ROR 5.0.

Comment: @cheops да, это часть `ActiveSupport`. Но `params` [имеет немножко другой тип: `ActionController::Parameters`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L109). И по-моему, он ещё и в четвёртых рельсах был.

Comment: @cheops, собственно, развивать тут особо нечего. Всё было сказано. Чтобы использовать `[]` и `[]=` необходимо и достаточно определить соответствующие методы. Я лишь уточнил, что в 4-х рельсах это было сделано за счёт наследования от `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, в пятых - от наследования отказались и методы определили явно.